# Phd in Mathematics (Analysis, Analytical Number Theory)

Tags: phd, mathematics

Does one have to study algebra at a graduate level (master's degree) in order to do a Phd related to complex analysis and analytical number theory, or functional analysis and PDE? Is a master's degree in analysis and PDE sufficient?

Comment: I'm not convinced this question is on topic here (it may be more about mathematics than academia in general), but I don't think it's a duplicate.  The proposed duplicate question deals with substantial changes of field, while moving between subfields can be rather different.  In U.S. mathematics departments, it's common to end up specializing in a subfield you have never studied at all before entering the graduate program.  Things may work differently in other countries, but this is in any case a very different situation from trying to get a Ph.D. in mathematics after studying, say, physics.

Comment: I agree it's not a duplicate, but I don't see any point in reopening it, just to close it as off-topic.